# Tab gets stuck at QComboBox after setting the tab order for navigation

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I created a form using QT (c++) consisting of different QLineEdits and QComboBox . Even after setting the tab order the tab gets stuck at the QComboBox.
The Tab looks something like this .. and the tab navigation works fine for QLineEdit but gets stuck on QComboBox . It does not move further

[image]

Comment: how are you setting the tab order? please post code and required info for verifying

Comment: I used QT designer to set the tab order by using Edit-> Edit Tab order .

Comment: could you share the tab view on the QtCreator?